# How to connect to a local server using windows hosted network

Tags: android, windows, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am programming an Android app which connects to a TCP server running on my computer using sockets. This works perfectly fine as long as both my computer and my smartphone are connected to the Wi-Fi of my router.

I want it to also work when my computer and my phone are not connected to the Wi-Fi. Therefore I configured a Wi-Fi hotspot using hosted network on my computer. My smartphone recognizes the Wi-Fi and is able to connect to it. But now my app can't connect to the server running on my PC although I changed the code to the new IP that I got by using ipconfig on my PC.

I downloaded an app named "Fing" from the Google play store. The app shows all devices in a network.  It does show my computer under the right IP address.  I don't understand why my app can't connect to the server running on the PC.

On the one hand, I don't think that the problem is in the app's code, because it works on the router's Wi-Fi network. On the other hand, I doesn't seem to be a setup mistake either, because Fing is detecting my PC.

Do you have any ideas what the problem might be, or any other solution for my needs?

Comment: Is the server app actually bound for listening on the hosted network IP? Or is it bound to a different IP that is also available on the PC? Did you write the TCP server yourself? Does it output anywhere what it is actually listening on?

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote the TCP server myself using c#. I configured the Server to listen to all of my computers networkinterfaces usingIPAdress.IPv6Any. I also did configure it as dual mode socket so it can accept ipv4 and ipv6 connections. I will post the code when i am back home. So the TCP server also looks ok to me.